# Clarification of Tillmann's construction of the higher genus surface operad

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, operads

Sorry if this question is inappropriate for overflow. I tried asking on stackexchange yesterday but didn't get any responses, so I thought that this site might be better. Anyway, my question is as follows:

I'm currently reading Tillmann's paper 'Higher genus surface operad detects infinite loop spaces' but am having trouble understanding the construction of said operad. Specifically, there are two points that I'd like clarification for:

1. The author says that the objects in the category $\mathcal{E}_{g,n,1}$ are of the form $(F,\sigma)$ where $F$ is a 'surface of topological type $F_{g,n+1}$ constructed from $D,P$ and $T$ by gluing the marked boundary of one of the surfaces to one of the free boundaries of another using the given parametrization'. I'm confused about the phrase "using the given parametrization"; is the parametrization considered part of the surface $F$?

   To be more specific, could we equivalently define the objects in this category as triples $(F,S,\sigma)$ where $F$ is a fixed surface with genus $g$ and $n+1$ boundary components and $S$ is a set of (isotopy classes of) simple closed curves in $F$ such that the complement of their images is a disjoint union of copies of $D,P$ and $T$ such that re-gluing along these curves follows the rules outlined in the paper?
2. The author then tells us to fix isotopies $\phi_1:\gamma(P;\_,P)\to\gamma(P;P,\_)$ and $\phi_2:\gamma(P;\_,D)\to\gamma(P;D,\_)$. I'm guessing that here $\gamma(P;\_,P)$ means the space given by gluing the fixed boundary of $P$ to the second free boundary of $P$ (and similarly for $D$). But then the author seems to be saying to chose an isotopy between spaces, which does not make sense to me. An isotopy is a relation between maps of spaces not between spaces themselves. How am I meant to interpret e.g. an isotopy $\phi:S^2\setminus\lbrace x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\rbrace\to S^2\setminus\lbrace y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4\rbrace$?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe you will find the Appendix to this paper helpful (I say maybe because I have only skimmed it):  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.07791.pdf

Comment: @DanRamras Thanks for the link! I had a read through the appendix and I'm not entirely sure it's helpful for my purposes. It does construct a similar operad in which gluing instructions do not seem to be part of the objects, but they also don't go through a lot of the quotient constructions in Tillmann's original paper.